# Does AWS S3 sync support calculating checksums of subsets of files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization

I want to download a large file incrementally from a S3 bucket. Each new version of the file I download may change slightly. Therefore, if the [s3 sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command computes a checksum of the *entire* new file, it will (likely) differ from the checksum of the old file, requiring the entire new file to be downloaded.

If, instead, s3 sync computes checksums on many small subsets of the file, it may find that only 1% of them do not match, meaning that only 1% of the file would need to be downloaded again.

Does s3 sync support comparing checksums of subsets of files? I read the manual page for [s3 sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) and could not find a clear answer.

Comment: The `aws s3 sync` command does not support downloading only the changed portion of a file. It will always download the full contents of a file. So it wouldn't make sense for it to perform checksums on only a portion of the file.

Comment: It would make sense for it to do this. It's just a question of whether it does do it. For example, if 9/10ths of my file is unchanged, calculating checksums on portions of the file could allow me to send 10% of the data I otherwise would, speeding up download. If you know that s3 sync does not support this, please provide a source!

Comment: Yes it would make sense if it supported both of those things (partial checksum and partial download), but since it doesn't support one of those things (partial download) then it doesn't make sense to support the other (partial checksum). I suggest you submit a feature request on the CLI tool's GitHub page: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues

Comment: Amazon S3 does not provide partial checksums, so it would not be possible to compare portions of a file against an object in S3. There is only one ETag for an S3 object.